# JSON to Long Table in Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON defined as a dict in python:

```
specs = {
    "state/79900116649511": {
        "active": {
            "window_size": 10000,
            "batch": True,
            "n_col": 50,
            "n_row": 200
        },
        "voltan": {
            "window_size": 50
        },
        "cura": {
            "window_size": 100
        }
    },
    "state/79900216649511": {
        "active": {
            "window_size": 10000,
            "batch": True,
            "n_col": 50,
            "n_row": 200
        },
        "voltan": {
            "window_size": 50
        },
        "cura": {
            "window_size": 100
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a long table from this dictionary. The output should be:

| state | variable | window_size | batch | n_col | n_row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 79900116649511 | active | 10000 | True | 50 | 200 |
| 79900116649511 | voltan | 50 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 79900116649511 | cura | 100 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 79900216649511 | active | 10000 | True | 50 | 200 |
| 79900216649511 | voltan | 50 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 79900216649511 | cura | 100 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

How can I do that? I thought about using nested loops, but that does not seem very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is either simple but works

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(specs, orient='index')
df = df.unstack(1).reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'level_0': 'variable', 'level_1': 'state'})
columns = df[0].iloc[0].keys()
for i in columns:
    df[i] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.get(i, None))
    
df = df.drop(columns=0)
df.state = df.state.apply(lambda x: x.replace('state/',''))
df = df[['state', 'variable', 'window_size', 'batch', 'n_col', 'n_row']].sort_values(by=['state'])
```

Results:

```
            state variable  window_size batch  n_col  n_row
0  79900116649511   active        10000  True   50.0  200.0
1  79900116649511   voltan           50  None    NaN    NaN
2  79900116649511     cura          100  None    NaN    NaN
3  79900216649511   active        10000  True   50.0  200.0
4  79900216649511   voltan           50  None    NaN    NaN
5  79900216649511     cura          100  None    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Can you print out your output?  Also, please include the import statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution as you use the first level key as "state" column, second level key as "variable" column, and only the rest as the column values that can be incomplete.

So you need at least two "loops" with special rules how to handle those keys.

Generally, to flatten/normalize a nested dict/json you can use the helper function `json_normalize` from the `pandas` library. For example if you only needed the top level keys from your json to be used as index, you could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for key in specs.keys():
    df = pd.json_normalize(specs[key])
    df.index = [key]
    dfs.append(df)
pd.concat(dfs)
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Sure, but that is no the expected output. Well, if I had all columns defined for every "state/variable" combination, that should do it, right?